# MVC4 nested accordion with foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to create a view using nested accordions and I'm not having much success so far.
I need the top accordion to be a category that will list a name which is the second accordion.

Another wrinkle in this is that I'm trying to use foreach to create a category accordion for each different category type, and then within that accordion, create an accordion for each name in the table.

Here is an example:

```
Historical(accordion)-> museum(accordion)-> description, state

Sports(accordion)->soccer(accordion)-> description, state

             ->baseball(accordion)-> description, state
```

Here is what I currently have but I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it or not:

```
<div id="accordioncat">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <h3>@item.category</h3>
    <div>
        <h3>@item.name</h3>
            <div>
                <p>@item.description</p>
                <p>@item.state</p>
            </div>
     </div>
}

</div>
```

With my model I'm using an int for category to join it to category id in my category table, and same with state.
Here is my model(this may need to be changed as well):

```
public class t_records
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Description")]
    public string description { get; set; }

    public int state { get; set; }

    public int category { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the data model would help. Are all items in the Model as a single list and not already categorized? That would be the first thing to start with, getting separate lists for each categories and then iterating the categories and then the items in those.